# Determining if a point is ordinary or singular in arbitrary ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

it is from section 5.3 
exercise 15:

Let $x$ and $x^2$ be solutions of Differential Equation:  $P(x)y'' + Q(x)y' +R(x)y=0$.
How to determine whether the point $x=0$ is an ordinary point or singular point?

I have found that $P(0)=0$. so, it looks like it is singular.
I checked the answer at the end of the book. It mentions about the initial conditions. It says: "Cannot specify arbitrary initial conditions at $x=0$, hence $x=0$ is a singular point"

Could you please explain this.